# UILabel Only Supports Certain Unicode Characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, swift

My app uses unicode characters. These characters (not the actual codes) are pasted directly into a PLIST file and then imported.

Some of them are not appearing correctly in UILabel and UIButton

When I print them to the log in Xcode they appear normal, but when displayed on the iPhone/Simulator some of the characters turn into an "alien in a box".

See image for example of problem (screenshot from UIButton titles)

[image]

Comment: Do they print correctly if you use the entities for them?

Comment: I think this should be solved using (embedded) fonts rather than relying on some undocumented erratic behaviour. Good luck with the localisation as well ;-).

Comment: An 'alien box' - sounds like a feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the font you are using does not define these characters. Select a font (or build one into your app) that includes the characters you need.

Comment: Duncan - are you saying you can build a font based on Unicode? The characters MUST be able to be used in the standard text messaging app

Comment: I'm saying that not all fonts include all characters. You need to pick a font that includes the characters you want. All fonts in iOS are "based on unicode".

Comment: that saved my life